# SQLAlchemy's merge doesn't fill foreign keys with ids of new objects in relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My question is when I have in a session a newly created object(doesn't have primary key yet, but will obtain it upon flush) and I merge to that session another object referring to the first one by relationship (*b* in the example) SQLAlchemy doesn't populate latter object with the primary key from the former.
Instead it just generate next value from the sequence. 
Why is it the case ?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker



engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://psql_admin:psql_admin@localhost/fm")



from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, VARCHAR, TEXT, Boolean, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column

class B(Base):
    __tablename__='B'
    id_=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(VARCHAR(30))

class Rel(Base):
    __tablename__='Rel'
    id_a=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_b=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('B.id_'), primary_key=True)
    b = relationship(B)
    rel_data=Column(VARCHAR(30))


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)   
session = Session()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)


first_b=B(id_=1, data='ololo')    
session.add(first_b)
session.commit()

session.add(Rel(id_a=800,id_b=1, rel_data='first relation data'))

second_b=B(data='foooo')
session.add(second_b)
x=session.merge(Rel(id_a=800, rel_data="second", b=second_b))
session.commit()
```

Here I have an error

> IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush;
>   consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occuring
>   prematurely) (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "B_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id_)=(1) already exists.  'INSERT
>   INTO "B" (data) VALUES (%(data)s) RETURNING "B".id_' {'data': 'foooo'}

Comment: May be you need to specify `back_populates` or `backref` in your relationship?